# Print clear TIF image

Tags: c#, .net, image, winforms, printing

I’m using WinForms, in my form I have a picture box and a print button. The problem is that the (TIF) image keeps becoming distorted after I print it. In the `print_preview_Settings()` i'm defining my own margins. To test, I print the tif image to a PDF, from there you can see the obvious distortion. How do I make this image print clear?

Below is the link of the test .tif image I use.

http://www.filedropper.com/display_1

This is the code that I’m currently using:

```
    using System.Drawing.Printing;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Load(@"C:\image\display.tif");
    }

    private void Print_Maintating_Aspect_Ratio_Of_Image(PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        var img_width = e.PageBounds.Width - e.MarginBounds.Left - Math.Abs(e.MarginBounds.Right - e.PageBounds.Width);
        var img_height = e.PageBounds.Height - e.MarginBounds.Top - Math.Abs(e.MarginBounds.Bottom - e.PageBounds.Height);


        var img = ResizeAcordingToImage(pictureBox1.Image, img_width, img_height);

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img,
            e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top, img.Width, img.Height);
    }

    private Image ResizeAcordingToImage(Image Source, int boxWidth, int boxHeight)
    {
        Image resizedImage;
        double dbl = (double)Source.Width / (double)Source.Height;
        //set height of image to boxHeight and check if resulting width is less than boxWidth, 
        //else set width of image to boxWidth and calculate new height
        if ((int)((double)boxHeight * dbl) <= boxWidth)
        {
            resizedImage = new Bitmap(Source, (int)((double)boxHeight * dbl), boxHeight);
        }
        else
        {
            resizedImage = new Bitmap(Source, boxWidth, (int)((double)boxWidth / dbl));
        }

        return resizedImage;

    }

    private void Print_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            printDocument1.Print();
        }
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        print_preview_Settings();

        Print_Maintating_Aspect_Ratio_Of_Image(e);
    }

    private void print_preview_Settings()
    {
        try {
            printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;

            int Top = 2;
            int Left = 1;
            int Right = 1;
            int Bottom = 3;

            printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = Top;
            printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = Left;
            printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = Right;
            printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = Bottom;


            printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Documented printed, but you got an error: "+ ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Why clone/resize the image? The DrawImage call can do it all for you. keep it simple! pick a unit you like and calculate a scale factor for the image.width&height or, better yet for the dpiX&Y of the image to print!

Comment: I want to be able to put margins in the picture and re-size it proportionately while keeping image quality  @TaW

Comment: Each time you resize an image, esp. if it has text on it, the image will be degraded. So best do it only once, when printing. adding a border may be a reason to create a copy but best without resizing. other than that you should use the debugger to keep an eye on the proportions..